# Sampling Order Statistics for Numerical Integration

Tags: monte-carlo, order-statistics

I want to do Monte Carlo integration over a region

$$ {\int}_{D_{1} \geq D_{2} \geq ... \geq D_{m} \geq 0} g(d_1,\ldots,d_m) f(d_1) f(d_2) \cdots f(d_m) \text{d}d_1\cdots\text{d}d_m$$

where $g$ is an arbitrary function and $f$ are density functions (either uniform or normal). My question is, for Monte Carlo integration over this region, can I simply draw $m$ samples from $f$ and sort them? If not, how do I sample points for this integration? If I were doing this in R, what function would I use to sample from this?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes this is correct, with a m! correction to add _[exercise]_ to compensate for the density of the ordered statistics. Simulation is thus straightforward if simulating from $f$ is straightforward.

Comment: @Xi'an That looks pretty close to a decent answer. Please consider making it one -- I don't think you'd need to add much, since you cover the main issues in those two sentences.

Comment: steve if `rf` generates from density $f$, and `g` computes $g$, then something along the lines of `replicate(nsim, {<...>} )` where `<...>` is a placeholder for a call to `g` with arguments being the sorted values generated from `rf`, the whole corrected by the factor for the ordering.

Comment: If this is for some subject, please add the `self-study` tag and read its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)

Comment: Why do you refer to "$f$" in the plural?  (If you intended to write $f_i(d_i)$, then the answer would be different.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a correct assessment of the problem since
$$
\int_{D_{1} \geq D_{2} \geq ... \geq D_{m} \geq 0} g(d_1,\ldots,d_m) f(d_1) f(d_2) \cdots f(d_m) \text{d}d_1\cdots\text{d}d_m
$$
can be turned into an expectation under the order statistics distribution
$$
m!\ \int g(d_1,\ldots,d_m) \dfrac{1}{m!}\mathbb{I}_{d_{1} \geq d_{2} \geq ... \geq d_{m} \geq 0}
f(d_1) f(d_2) \cdots f(d_m) \text{d}d_1\cdots\text{d}d_m
$$
(hence the missing factor $m!$). And simulating a sample from the order statistics is straightforward:

```
mean(g(t(apply(matrix(rt(1000,2),nr=100,nc=10),1,sort)))
```

where `g` is your function of interest (and `rt` is the $t$-distribution generator, to be replaced with yours).